# Running an object's method from within a static method

Tags: static-methods

I have two classes: Board, Player. The Board class uses static methods to calculate what happens when a player lands on a certain space on the board.

I pass the player object, p1, into the Board class. One of the static methods in the Board class needs to access methods in the p1 object. I have a basic understanding that static methods belong to the class and not the instance, but is there a way to access p1's methods without making p1 static?

Answer (score 0):

Offcourse you can invoke INSTANCE method of Player since you have REFERENCE TO PLAYER OBJECT

```
class Board{
   public static void land(Player p1){
     p1.performAction();
   }
}
```

What you cannot do, is invoke an INSTANCE METHOD OF BOARD class, since the static method in board class is not executed in the context of an instance.

Thus, compiler will spit out error if you try to do this -

```
class Board{
       public static void land(){
         performAction();
       }
       private void performAction(){
              //instance method
       }

    }
```

However, you can invoke an instance method from another instance method, below would work - since while invoking doAction() from performAction() you are already in the context of an instance

```
class Board{

       private void performAction(){
              doAction();
       }

        private void doAction(){
        }
    }
```